# Basic UNIX link count

Tags: unix, directory, hyperlink, ls

Why is the link count 2?

```
$ mkdir testdir
$ ls -ld testdir
drwxr-xr-x  2 me  you  68 Mar 29 12:34 testdir/
```

Perhaps it refers to a link to itself and link from parent directory?

I'm just reading through [The UNIX Programming Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X) and learning the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a directory, it always has two (special) subdirectories: `.` and `..`, which refer to the directory itself and its parent, respectively.  If you add more sub directories, the link count increases from there.